# Active mq fail-over transport produce memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, activemq-classic, failover

I am using the active mq fail-over transport  configuration (master only) in my Spring Web based application. 
Version 5.8.0

After some period of producing/consuming messages, out-of-memory occurs. Transaction mode is enabled. For any session commit or rollback invoked properly.

Memory analizer shows leak suspect:  *One instance of "org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport" loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xfc0e9a40" occupies 28,711,384 (46.09%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]" loaded by "".*

Any ideas. Thanks in advance

Comment: No idea about the answer but why do people down vote questions without leaving a reason? To me, this question is absolutely fine and makes complete sense.

Comment: Ever figure this one out? I've the same problem.